# new Relic -how to pass custom Strings

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I'd like to set a tag in [new Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/) and have it show up on the new relic dashboard.  For example.  I'd like to do something like this in psuedocode:

newRelic.setString("status","Disabled");

am i able to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can collect so called custom parameters, metrics or use custom events.

This is an example of a ruby code, but the following does apply for a Java lib also.

```rb
class Cart

  def checkout()
    amount = compute_cart_total    # computes the amount to charge the customer

    ::NewRelic::Agent.record_metric('Custom/Cart/charge_amount', amount)

    charge_customer(amount)
    ...
  end
end
```

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/other-features/metrics/custom-metrics

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/other-features/attributes/collecting-custom-attributes

Comment: would it be something like this:  NewRelic.addCustomParameter("userId", userId);